# Draw Rectangle over PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, mouseevent, picturebox

The next code lets you draw Rectangles in the Form with mouse clics.
Why not, or how can be draw over a PictureBox?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim SelectRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
Dim ps As Point = New Point()
Dim pe As Point = New Point()
```

This catch the first click, starting point or corner of the rectangle

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    SelectRect.Width = 0
    SelectRect.Height = 0
    SelectRect.X = e.X
    SelectRect.Y = e.Y
    ps.X = e.X
    ps.Y = e.Y
    pe = ps
End Sub
```

This part determine the width and height of the rectangle:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(Me.RectangleToScreen(SelectRect), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
        SelectRect.Width = e.X - SelectRect.X
        SelectRect.Height = e.Y - SelectRect.Y
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(Me.RectangleToScreen(SelectRect), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
    End If

End Sub
```

This part determine the last coordinate, the second corner of the rectangle:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Blue, 2)
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(Me.RectangleToScreen(SelectRect), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
    g.DrawRectangle(p, SelectRect)
    g.Dispose()
End Sub
   End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's the same thing.

Comment: Always use the PaintEvent for all drawing.  `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong thing to do

Comment: @Jimi Its similar, I find this code earlier, this one lets you draw rectangles by hand (not programatically assigned locations) directly over the Form but if you have a PictureBox the drawing just can be done at back (Form) -if some part remains visible-,  but you cannot draw over the PictureBox. Thats the problem

Comment: Let me understand. Do you want to draw on a PictureBox only? Or both Form and PictureBox? In other words, you have that code but you don't know how to adapt it to draw shapes on a different control. Is that it?

Comment: If you're not handling the `Paint` event the you're doing it wrong. The `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events should only recording the mouse position and then forcing a repaint by calling `Refresh` or `Invalidate` and `Update`. The drawing should all be done in the `Paint` event handler, as is ALWAYS the case. NEVER call `CreateGraphics`.

Comment: Also, if you want to draw on a `PictureBox` then you need to handle events of that `PictureBox`. If you handle events of the form then you can only draw on the form. It's the same events but they need to be events of the control you want to draw on.

Comment: if you need to use creategraphics always use USING...otherwise you create a memory leak

Comment: @Jimi Is for the same: the code you know https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlqVaIM2GTrSlTmW9VKyqG1KzOoE the purpouse of pictures section is: tagging groupal photos as facebook does with invisible rectangles that show the names if you move mouse over. In the program when run it you Click on the sun character at right bottom corner, this show "edit" Button, the idea its lets the user draw the rectangles over the PictureBox (photo) then show a textbox to write the person name, at exit save the coordinates + person name as string into .txt file with the name of the picture, to read easily when is showing.

Comment: @Jimi Yes! i think this code can be very useful for that purpose, lets to see to user a visual reference of the rectangles you have, but difficult save coordinates as strings and get it back to set the rectangles... starting by the fact: I can't draw rectangles over a picturebox!... the method of using overlayer for photo's title works fine maybe can be adapted here too but cause the problem of anticopy text if check checkbox1 a twice.. as form defocus but is not.

Comment: LOL. Sorry, I did't notice your nick. About the overlay, I'll get back to you in the context of your other Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses a control (a Form in this case) mouse events to enable the drawing of rectangular shapes, with the help of guidelines, provided by `Control.DrawReversibleFrame()`.
You just have to define the same events of a different, drawable, control - like a PictureBox - and repeat, more or less, the same procedure (after a cleanup).

> As **many** have stated, here and before, use the Graphics object that
>   the Paint event kindly offers, so that your drawing will persist.
>   The Graphics object you get from Control.CreateGraphics() is not
>   persistent, and it can be erase/clipped when you don't want to.
>   Use it only if that is really what you have **planned to do** for the
>   reasons you know.

---

I've adden an event handler that checks if `Control Key` is pressed.
If `Control` is pressed, you add a rectangle, if not, only one rectangle is drawn.
I've also included, as an example, a line of code that fills the rectangle. I think it's interesting, because you have to control the size of the invalidated Region.
Comment out these lines of code to draw just the frame:

```
SelectRect.Inflate(CInt(-_pen.Width / 2), CInt(-_pen.Width / 2))
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_brush, SelectRect)
```

[image]

```
Dim SelectRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
Dim _pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Green, 4)
Dim _brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Orange)
Dim _ControlPressed As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    _ControlPressed = (e.Modifiers And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    _ControlPressed = (e.Modifiers And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    SelectRect.Location = e.Location
    SelectRect.Size = New Size(0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(PictureBox1.RectangleToScreen(SelectRect), PictureBox1.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed)
        SelectRect.Width = e.X - SelectRect.X
        SelectRect.Height = e.Y - SelectRect.Y
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(PictureBox1.RectangleToScreen(SelectRect), PictureBox1.BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp

    If (e.Y < SelectRect.Y) Then
        SelectRect.Location = If(SelectRect.Location.X > e.X,
                                 New Point(e.X, e.Y), New Point(SelectRect.X, e.Y))
        SelectRect.Size = New Size(Math.Abs(SelectRect.Width), Math.Abs(SelectRect.Height))
    Else
        If SelectRect.Location.X > SelectRect.Right Then
            SelectRect.Location = New Point(e.X, SelectRect.Y)
            SelectRect.Size = New Size(Math.Abs(SelectRect.Width), Math.Abs(SelectRect.Height))
        End If
    End If

    If _ControlPressed Then
        Dim _InflatedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(SelectRect.Location, SelectRect.Size)
        _InflatedRect.Inflate(CInt(_pen.Width / 2), CInt(_pen.Width / 2))
        PictureBox1.Invalidate(_InflatedRect)
    Else
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    'Draw the outer rectangle with the color of _pen
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(_pen, SelectRect)

    'Fill the rectangle with the color of _brush
    'It's half Pen.Width smaller so it doesn't erase the contour
    SelectRect.Inflate(CInt(-_pen.Width / 2), CInt(-_pen.Width / 2))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_brush, SelectRect)

End Sub
```

Comment: i never advice before: RULE: the rectangles must be draw left to right and top to bottom... but now works great over picturebox!

Comment: @arc95  You're right I didn't check that. I've updated the code: now you can draw a frame/box in any direction.

Comment: Wow nice piece of code, it help me a lot!!, I update the project!! can you help me to determine individual rectangles? the code already save coordinates and "suggested name" on txt file when you add rectangles at edition mode but I dont know how to get back the names/rectangles or place in labels near to the rectangles. issue: when you click on the picturebox the "suggest a name" TextBox appears!, 
Also I work a lot in the catalog part and books part, little problem line 77 at frmbooks.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlqVaIM2GTrSlTmW9VKyqG1KzOoE
It show a message if you click the rectangle zone